# How to remove drag highlighting with GWT

Tags: gwt

is there way to remove drag highlighting within a  GWT app without removing the capability to highlight GWT TextBox texts? Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By adding a NativePreviewHandler and checking native events target to prevent default behaviour

```
        final TextBox t = new TextBox();
        t.setText("Can select me");
        Label prevent = new Label("Can't select me");
        RootPanel.get().add(t);
        RootPanel.get().add(prevent);

        Event.addNativePreviewHandler(new NativePreviewHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onPreviewNativeEvent(NativePreviewEvent event) {
                EventTarget target = event.getNativeEvent().getEventTarget();
                if (!target.equals(t.getElement())){
                    event.getNativeEvent().preventDefault();
                }
            }
        });
```